# Flashlight not turning on when entering trigger zone

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I have a trigger zone that when the players enter the flashlight goes off.  This part works.  However when the player enters the second trigger zone the flashlight does not turn on again.  Not sure why this is happening?

Here is my code I am using:

First Trigger Zone:

```
var point_light: Light;
var point_light1: Light;

function OnTriggerEnter(other: Collider) {

point_light.enabled = false;
point_light1.enabled = false;

}
```

Second Trigger Zone:

```
var point_light: Light;
var point_light1: Light;

function OnTriggerEnter(other: Collider) {

point_light.enabled = true;
point_light1.enabled = true;

}
```

Second trigger zone does not work.
Can some one please help?

Thanks

Comment: The problem may not come from the code but the parameters of your triggers. Have you checked the `isTrigger` checkbox ? Are you sure the colliders and rigidbody(ies) are ok ? Have you checked if [the layers are "compatible" for collision detection](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LayerBasedCollision.html) ?

Comment: Yeah have checked all of that but still not working :-(

Comment: Have you assigned the values of `point_light` in the inspector?

Comment: is the gameobject active?Is the collider active? Is its size large enough?

Comment: Is this just one area or two? If it is just one area (such as room) that should only turn off the light when entered, and turn the light back on when you leave, then I would recommend using `OnTriggerExit()`